# Find element within parent container with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to target an element within my LI only im having trouble, I've read the jQuery documentation but cant figure out what im doing wrong?

On a click event I want to find an element and alter the html inside...

http://jsfiddle.net/68ePW/3/

```
<li>
    <h2>400</h2>
    <form>
        <input type='submit' class='click' value='send'>                
    </form>
</li>

$('.click').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('li').closest('h4').html('asdasd');
});
```

Comment: Which element? And do what to it? Show your code **here**, JS Fiddle's a nice extra, but your questions should make sense, and retain their usefulness, without relying on external sites.

Comment: I think you meant to use 'h2' as the parameter for closest()

Comment: `$(this).closest('li').find('h2')` ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Based on the following HTML (bear in mind I had to wrap the `li` with the `ul`, since an unwrapped `li` is invalid HTML):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>400</h2>
        <form>
            <input type='submit' class='click' value='send'>                
        </form>
    </li>    
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And the following jQuery:

```
$('.click').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('li').closest('h4').html('asdasd');
});
```

It seems you're trying to find the `h4` within the `li`. The problems you're having are multiple:

1. Using `parent()` only looks up to the immediate parent element of the current element; use `closest()` instead, to look up through the ancestors *until* it finds a matching element,
2. `closest()` (as mentioned) looks *up* through the ancestor elements, while you're trying to find an element among the descendants of the `li` element. Use `find()`,
3. You were searching for an `h4` element, which didn't exist. You needed (I assume) to find the `h2` that was present in the DOM.

So:

```
$('.click').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find('h2').html('asdasd');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/68ePW/6/).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Comment: Thanks @David Thomas, I see it works on jsfiddle only it doesnt on my actual site, on page load the form is initially display:none and only becomes visible when a button top toggle its view is clicked, could this be the reason?

Comment: I don't know; to answer that we'd have to see your site, and have some idea of what's going on there.

Comment: "I see it works on jsfiddle only it doesnt on my actual site" --- and now **your** work is to get it worked. We're here to get the idea of how to do that, not to do everything for you.