# Check Input when Select with same class change

Tags: jquery, html

I actually have this code but I do not wanted to write it for every select (since I have more than 10 select and that it will change with time).

```
$('select.myClass').on('change', function() {
  $('input.myClass').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Is it possible to make it better with something like "if a select option is changed, check the input with the same class as the changed option"?

**Codepen UPDATED with answer from [sojtin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4108518/sojtin)**

https://codepen.io/Qasph/pen/pPjrpx

Comment: What is your exact problem? Seems to me a XY problem

Comment: try this $('select').on('change', function() {
  
class_val =  $(this).attr('class');
  $('input.'+class_val).prop('checked', true);
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have single class for select, try this:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('input.'+$(this).prop('class')).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input class="level" type="checkbox">This is
</label>
<select class="level">
  <option>easy</option>
  <option>hard</option>
  <option>impossible</option>
</select>

<label>
  <input class="asdfasdf" type="checkbox">This is
</label>
<select class="asdfasdf">
  <option>easy</option>
  <option>hard</option>
  <option>impossible</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please find below snippet on `change` of `select` get selected value and find checkbox with the `class` with same class as selected value

```js
$('.'+ $('.level').val()).prop('checked', true);
$('.level').on('change', function() {
$(".common").prop('checked',false);
  $('.'+ $(this).val()).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input class="common easy" type="checkbox">easy
</label>
<label>
  <input class="common hard" type="checkbox">hard
</label>
<label>
  <input class="common impossible" type="checkbox">impossible
</label>
<select class="level">
  <option>easy</option>
  <option>hard</option>
  <option>impossible</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your current case

```
$('select').change(function(){
  var target = $(this).attr('class');
  $('input.'+target).prop('checked', true);
});
```

I suggest adding an ID with the same value to the target with the above code and change it to

```
$('select').change(function(){
  var target = $(this).attr('id');
  $('input.'+target).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use select as `selector` `on change` you can get the class name of current element and concat `$('input.'+class_val)` like this to check the same class checkbox

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  
class_val =  $(this).attr('class');
  $('input.'+class_val).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input class="level" type="checkbox">This is
</label>
<select class="level">
 <option>select</option>
  <option>easy</option>
  <option>hard</option>
  <option>impossible</option>
</select>

<label>
  <input class="level1" type="checkbox">This is
</label>
<select class="level1">
  <option>select</option>
  <option>easy1</option>
  <option>hard1</option>
  <option>impossible1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pack inputs in outer `div`, use `closest("div")` to find him and inside search for `input.level`, see Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVyxgZ. Based ot this SO question: [Find element within parent container with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325101/find-element-within-parent-container-with-jquery) . With this solution, you can have many selects with the same CSS classes - it's easier to style them.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the best way to check them for my project. All my inputs are in the same ul, so it would probably not work.

Comment: That's ok, but - do you have `<ul><select>.....`? If you have, it's not valid HTML, you should have `<ul><li><select>....`. `li` is only valid descendant for `ul` (and inside `li` other tags are valid). Good luck!